# In my screenplay(spec, I believe) can I use "we see..." in action line?

Tags: screenwriting

I'm not sure if this is okay, (also: we hear...) I realize that typically the sentence would say the same thing if removed but it seems to work in the midst of an action line like:

> Close on Bathsheba's distraught face in the rain we hear another CAR DOOR OPEN.
>
> Over her shoulder we see Bishop Caringless standing at the window she came out of. Focused on him we hear Bathsheba scream along with a struggle.
>
> We then see the two men carry her to their car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use it! Do not use "we hear", either. See:

http://reelauthors.com/screenplay-coverage/do-not-use-we-see.php

Don't give camera directions (focused on...) Sounds are just in CAPS. If you want the above sequence, use CUTS.

> CLOSE ON BATHSHEBA's distraught face in the rain. A CAR DOOR OPENS.
>
> CUT TO:
>
> BISHOP CARINGLESS standing at the window she left [insert visual description here, eg 'stone faced' or 'angry' or 'haughty']
>
> O.S. BATHSHEBA SCREAMS and is SILENCED. Sounds of STRUGGLE. BISHOP CARINGLESS turns calmly and leaves the window.
>
> CUT TO:
>
> TWO MEN carry the unconscious BATHSHEBA to their car.

(edit: I fixed formatting a bit... char names in caps, etc)

Comment: Thank you you've helped me a lot, examples in the best books don't always cover exactly what u need